# Should hdiutil create image from physical or synthesized disk?

Tags: backup, recovery, disk-image, hdiutil

When using `hdiutil` to create a backup image from a terminal in recovery mode (Command-R)

`hdiutil create -srcdevice /dev/disk3 /Volumes/backups/<name>`

where `disk3` is the "synthesized" drive (see diskutil output below),

should `/dev/disk0` (internal, physical) be sourced instead?

The image (.dmg) would be used for a full restore, although individual file browsing/restoration would be nice too (which seems like sourcing disk3 should provide for)?

---

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         500.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +1.2 GB     disk1
   1:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         1.2 GB     disk1s1

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.2 GB     disk2
                                 Physical Store disk1s1
   1:                APFS Volume macOS Base System       942.9 MB   disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 81.3 MB    disk2s2

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk3
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.8 GB    disk3s1
   2:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     91.9 GB    disk3s2
   3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 3.6 GB     disk3s3
   4:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.1 GB     disk3s4
   5:                APFS Volume VM                      20.5 KB    disk3s5
```

---

[**Note**:](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/create-a-disk-image-dskutl11888/mac) You can’t create images of individual APFS volumes. You can’t create images of APFS containers on Mac computers with Apple silicon or an Apple T2 Security Chip.

Comment: Is there a reason why you’re not using `asr` to make the image and backup? That is the tool I would chose but perhaps you have reasons to not use that so I’d rather not answer if you have requirements or constraints I didn’t anticipate.

Comment: @bmike I will look into `asr`. I'll use any tool that is built-in, and can be run from recovery (with the OS down, for integrity's sake). Can Time Machine restore form `asr` images?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? You mention "restore". If disaster recovery is your purpose, why not Time Machine (or CCC, etc.)?

Comment: @Gilby Primarily for rolling back major releases with performance issues or corruption, so I suppose disaster recovery. `Time Machine`'s incrementals save significant space and is simple to use. `asr` clones but doesn't image, which is OK in this case. `Disk Utility` or `hdutil` seem like the best options if an image is actually needed.